# How to use GLKMathProject? [GLKit - iOS]

Tags: ios, sdk, glkit

I tried:

```
int viewport[4];
viewport[0] = 0;
viewport[1] = 480;
viewport[2] = 320;
viewport[3] = 480;

GLKVector3 x = GLKMathProject(position, effect.transform.modelviewMatrix, effect.transform.projectionMatrix, viewport);

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromGLKVector3(x));
```

position is a GLKVector3 like this {3, 5, 6}

But it gives me some strange values: {1.52313e+12, 8.0313e+08, -160.131}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left most of the viewport array uninitialized. You probably meant:

```
int viewport[4];
viewport[0] = 0;
viewport[1] = 480;
viewport[2] = 320;
viewport[3] = 480;
```

Or, shorter:

```
int viewport[4] = {0, 480, 320, 480};
```

Sidenote: Shouldn't it be `{0, 0, 320, 480}` (origin at 0, 0)?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just copied and pasted wrong. But I meant the viewport like you wrote.
Anyway, the problem I think it's with the viewport. What's strange is that the documentation says that the viewport is "A pointer to an array of four integer values. The first pair of values represent the window coordinates of the viewport’s bottom left corner. The second pair of values represent the width and height of the view point."
From what I understand, the bottom left corner is 0, 480. No?
Anyway I accept your question cause it solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Davide The viewport is in OpenGL coordinates and they have the origin in the lower left with an upwards pointing y axis.